# How to programmatically connect to a WCF service that is hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, wcf, wcf-binding

The bindings and client end points of my WCF service that is hosted in IIS look like below.

```
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
          <binding name="notSecureBinding">
              <binaryMessageEncoding />
              <httpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
          </binding>
          <binding name="SecureBinding">
              <binaryMessageEncoding />
              <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
          </binding>
      </customBinding>
  </bindings>



<client>
      <endpoint address="http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="notSecureBinding"
                contract="GetData.GetData"
                name="notSecureBinding" />

      <endpoint address="https://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc"
                binding="customBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="SecureBinding"
                contract="GetData.GetData"
                name="SecureBinding" />
  </client>
```

Now what i want to do is to connect to this service and read the data i want with out adding any Service References to my asp.net mvc 4 application.

I tried this code below

```
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc");
IService1 ADUser = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(basicHttpBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
DataTable ADUserInfo = ADUser.GetADUserList(strUserName, strFirstName, strLastName, strEmail, domain);
```

But the code above throws the error below.

> The message with Action 'http://tempuri.org/IService1/GetADUserList' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

It does seem like a binding mismatch because in WCF config, i'm using "customBinding" but i'm unable to define that in C# code, only found "BasicHttpBinding".

Does any one one know how i can successfully connect to this IIS hosted WCF service via C# code and call my "GetADUserList" method with out adding a service reference to my MVC application?

Comment: You're not using a BasicHttpBinding on the server from what I can see.  You're using a CustomBinding.  You are also using a contract of GetData.GetData, not IService1.

Answer (score 0):

There is a `CustomBinding` class in the `System.ServiceModel` namespace that you can use.

```
Binding customBinding = new CustomBinding(
             new BinaryMessageEncodingBindingElement(),
             new HttpTransportBindingElement 
             { 
               MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647, 
               MaxBufferSize = 2147483647 
             });
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("http://ServerName.myDomain.org/ADSearcher/Service1.svc");
IService1 ADUser = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(customBinding, endpointAddress).CreateChannel();
```